# How to resolve this integration $\int\frac{dx}{1+x^2+\sin^2x}$?

Tags: calculus, integration, indefinite-integrals

I have tried Trigonometric Substitution, but I can´t get an already known function to be easy for integrate:

$$\int\frac{dx}{1+x^2+\sin^2x}$$

I entered this on Wolfram and it gave me the same function. I'm not asking for the exact solution, just a good way to solve it.

Regards.

Comment: I'll bet you a nickel that there's a $dx$ in their somewhere.

Comment: I'm sorry, yes it is.

Comment: @John. In "their" or "there" :)

Comment: Sorry about the question, but we use different notation. Is it $\sin x^2$ or $\sin^2 x$?

Comment: The second, sin^2 (x), I´m using mathjax first time.

Comment: It is highly possible that an exact antiderivative might not exist without using special functions.

Comment: @imranfat Oh gosh, that was an awful slip.

Comment: @robjohn what do you mean with special functions?

Comment: @ismatim: special functions are functions not attainable as the composition of the basic four functions $+,-,\times,\div$, the trigonometric, and exponential functions (the exponential functions include logarithms).

Comment: @Vadim That's the reason I'm parenthesis fanatic.

Answer (score 3):

Hint:

$\because0\leq\dfrac{\sin^2x}{x^2+1}<1$ $\forall x\in\mathbb{R}$

$\therefore\int\dfrac{dx}{1+x^2+\sin^2x}$

$=\int\dfrac{dx}{(x^2+1)\left(1+\dfrac{\sin^2x}{x^2+1}\right)}$

$=\int\dfrac{1}{x^2+1}\sum\limits_{m=0}^\infty\dfrac{(-1)^m\sin^{2m}x}{(x^2+1)^m}dx$

$=\int\dfrac{1}{x^2+1}dx+\int\sum\limits_{m=1}^\infty\dfrac{(-1)^m\sin^{2m}x}{(x^2+1)^{m+1}}dx$

$=\int\dfrac{1}{x^2+1}dx+\int\sum\limits_{m=1}^\infty\dfrac{(-1)^m(2m)!}{4^m(m!)^2(x^2+1)^{m+1}}dx+\int\sum\limits_{m=1}^\infty\sum\limits_{n=1}^m\dfrac{(-1)^{m+n}(2m)!\cos2nx}{2^{2m-1}(m-n)!(m+n)!(x^2+1)^{m+1}}dx$

$=\int\dfrac{1}{x^2+1}dx+\int\sum\limits_{m=1}^\infty\dfrac{(-1)^m(2m)!}{4^m(m!)^2(x^2+1)^{m+1}}dx+\int\sum\limits_{m=1}^\infty\sum\limits_{n=1}^m\sum\limits_{p=0}^\infty\dfrac{(-1)^{m+n+p}(2m)!4^pn^{2p}x^{2p}}{2^{2m-1}(m-n)!(m+n)!(2p)!(x^2+1)^{m+1}}dx$